# Shared NSHTTPCookieStorage will sync persistent cookies to WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore httpCookieStore?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, nshttpcookiestorage, wkhttpcookiestore

I found an interesting fact that the shared `NSHTTPCookieStorage` will sync **persistent** cookies(`isSessionOnly=false`) to `WKWebsiteDataStore.defaultDataStore.httpCookieStore`,
could anyone tell me if this is a feature or kind of unreliable behavior?
No documentation ever found for this...

Tested on iOS 13.2.2 & 12.1

POC

**Step1.** Create a persistent cookie

```
var props = Dictionary<HTTPCookiePropertyKey, Any>()
props[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name] = "HelloWorld"
props[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value] = "666"
props[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path] = "/"
props[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain] = ".wtf.com"
props[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires] = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 60)

let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: props)
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie!)
```

**Step2.** Read the previous cookie from the default WK storage

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
    for cookie in cookies {
        if cookie.name == "HelloWorld" { 
            NSLog("boommmmmmm!")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any updates on this please

Comment: It's a feature. Now we can use NSHTTPCookieStorage.acceptCookiePolicy to bypass the default ITP imposed on WKWebView. What a surprise...

Comment: FYI, it also syncs to WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent and only works on a real device. Doesn't work in a simulator. Tested on iOS 14.5